# How to pass a value to ARG in Dockerfile from lauchsettings.json in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: dockerfile, visual-studio-2022

I have the following dockerfile (confidencial stuff replaced)

```
FROM my-proxy/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM my-proxy/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
ARG NUGET_REPO
RUN dotnet restore "MyService.csproj" --source ${NUGET_REPO}
RUN dotnet build "MyService.csproj" -c Release --no-restore -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyService.csproj" -c Release --no-restore -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

i need to pass a value to arg NUGET_REPO. In a pipeline in Gitlab, i can pass `--build-arg NUGET_REPO=http://mylink.url` to Kaniko executor, and all works fine.

The question is: how can i pass the arg value from Visual Studio 2022, using built-in launchSettings.json profile:

```
"TEST Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/ping",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Test"
  }
},
```

There's an option to pass `docker run` parameters, but there's no option to pass `docker build` parameters.

My target is to use the similar Dockerfile both for Kaniko executor and local VS2022 run. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Taken a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022)? There's property `DockerfileBuildArguments` that allows you to pass arguments to `docker build` command but this is set in your project file.